# Flutter doctor command doesn't work on Visual studio Code terminal, error massage: bash: flutter: command not found

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Flutter doctor work on terminal full path but dose not work on VS code terminal or another path on pc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need restart your computer after edit environment path

Answer (score 0):

You need to have each path on separate line. That's what I have.
click NEW and then enter your path like below

```
C:\src\flutter\bin
```

Then restart

Edit: I would suggest you add your git and all the other paths also on separate line. you should be very careful with environment variables.

Comment: please mark answered if it helped so that others also can get the correct answer. Glad I could help.